# Proving that cartesian product is a group

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I need to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)\times
(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ is a group. Now, I am familiar with the conditions of being a group, but still, I can't see how can I show that she has a natural number, the existence of opposite numbers, etc...
My idea by intuition was to show that  $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ is a group, and therefore his cartesian product by itself is a group, but I don't know of such theorem.

Thanks!

Comment: Let $(g_1,h_1)+(g_2,h_2)=(g_1+g_2,h_1+h_2)$

Comment: @Kenta S According to what you saying that?

Comment: I am saying that is a natural way to define an operation on $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$, which makes it a group.

Comment: @KentaS However, how do I show the criteria of being a group, I mean this is what I need to do, am I?

Comment: The direct product (Cartesian product) of two groups is always a group. You don't need that the group law is addition, it is always true.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is it a theorem? because if so I will be glad if you can show me that way of proving this. If not so, does it an axiom?

Comment: Yes, it is a theorem. The duplicate question proves it by checking all axioms, right? Associativity, neutral element, inverse element etc. for the group law $(g,h)\cdot (g',h')=(gg',hh')$.  Have a look again. You can also take any book on group theory or abstract algebra and read the proof there.

Comment: So you are saying that is right, when I have a group, then her cartesian product always yields a group, right? because she by herself holds all axioms of being a group.

Comment: Yes, google "direct product of groups", or start reading the duplicate.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you so much!